# Multithreaded Rails server for Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7-x64, thin, unicorn

I need to install a multithreaded (to support Facebook Open graph callbacks) on Windows.
Is it possible?

I tried thing but it doesn't install (event machine does not compile).
Unicorn doesn't seem to have a Windows version.

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> gem install thin --platform=x86-mingw32

```
 Fetching: rack-1.4.1.gem (100%)
 Fetching: eventmachine-0.12.10.gem (100%)
 Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
 Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
 Fetching: daemons-1.1.8.gem (100%)
 Fetching: thin-1.3.1.gem (100%)
 Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
 Successfully installed rack-1.4.1
 Successfully installed eventmachine-0.12.10
 Successfully installed daemons-1.1.8
 Successfully installed thin-1.3.1
```

This works for me on  Windows-7-x64 prepared with [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/)